# how to allow for factor-specific variance of random effect in lme

Tags: r, variance, mixed-models, random-effects

I assume that the random effects variances in my mixed effect model will be different for different levels of the fixed factor `BTyp`.

Here is my model

```
fm2 <- lme(CA ~ 1 + pF+Tiefe+BTyp+Tiefe:pF+BTyp:pF, data=data2, 
           random = list(~ 1 + pF|Probe))
fm2_Btyphet<-update(fm2, weights=varIdent(form=~1|BTyp))
```

I managed to incorporate `Btyp`-specific variances for random effects using `lmer` function, but this function does not allow to consider variance heterogeneity of the within group error (which is better to consider in my case). **My question is how to incorporate "Btyp"-specific variances for random effects using `lme` function?**

Below you can see how it works with `lmer` function.

```
CA ~ 1 + pF + Tiefe + BTyp + Tiefe:pF + BTyp:pF + 
     (0 + Pind + pF | Probe) + (0 + Bind + pF | Probe) + (0 + Tind + pF | Probe) 


 Data: data2 

 AIC   BIC logLik deviance REMLdev

   21987 22092 -10975    21979   21951

Random effects:
 Groups   Name Variance Std.Dev. Corr 

 Probe    Pind 158.6058 12.5939         
          pF     2.4289  1.5585  -1.000 

 Probe    Bind 134.6383 11.6034         
          pF     2.7619  1.6619  -1.000 

 Probe    Tind 490.6714 22.1511         
          pF    46.3533  6.8083  -1.000 

 Residual      316.9860 17.8041    

Number of obs: 2530, groups: Probe, 45
```

`Pind`,`Bind`, `Tind` are indicator variables for different levels of `BTyp`.

Comment: Maybe a nested random effect would be appropriate? `random = ~ 1 + pF|BTyp/Probe` or `random = ~ 1 + pF|Probe/BTyp` (there is not much information about the experimental design in your question)

Comment: Thank you Roland, this BTyp was not a fixed factor, therefore I guess i cannot use nested random effect