# General linear mixed-effect (glmer) heteroscedasticity modelling

Tags: r

My variables are measured on a randomized block with a subsampling design where my treatments are the 23 Accesion. I have 3 complete blocks and 6 samples per block. The example dataframe has 4 response variables (LH, REN, FTT, DFR), Accesion (treatment), Bloque (Block number) and Plot (that is the variable accounting for the subsampling). The head of the data is:

```
  Plot Accesion Bloque   LH  REN FTT DFR
1  221       22      1 20.6 1127  23  88
2  221       22      1 20.5 1638  20  88
3  221       22      1 24.5 1319  16  88
4  221       22      1 21.4  960  17  88
5  221       22      1 25.7 1469  18  88
6  221       22      1 25.8 1658  21  88
```

So, the data is non-normal and heteroscedastic for almost all of the 100 response variables after all types of transformations (log, boxcox, power, etc). Most of the variables show a chi-squared or Poisson-like distribution with different variance for each Accesion.

[image: Histogram for FTT]

So far I've beeng working on running a generalized linear model-effect with Poisson using the `glmer()` on the FTT as a response variable. I am using this code:

```
FTTglme = glmer(FTT ~ Accesion + Bloque + (1|Plot), data = Lyc,   
family=poisson(link="identity"))
```

The residuals are non-normal according to the shapiro.test(). That, I assume, is because of the heteroscedasticity observed in the residuals. As a boxplot of the residuals by Accesion, shows the difference of variances:

[image: Boxplot of Residuals by Accesion]

The heteroscedasticity is expected between plant populations, but I know it can be modelled inside the glme. The code that I should add, as I have investigated already, is:

```
vf <- varIdent(form=~Accesion)

FTTglme = glmer(FTT ~ Accesion + Bloque + (1|Plot), data = Lyc,   
family=poisson(link="identity"), weights = vf)
```

I want the different variances to account for each Accesion category. But I keep getting the error:

> ```
> Error in model.frame.default(data = Lyc, weights = varIdent(form = ~Accesion),  : 
>   variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')
> ```

Does anyone know how to account for the differences of variance between the Accesions inside the `glmer()`?

Any other suggestions to analyze the data is also welcome.

Comment: (1) why an identity link? (2) you're trying to mix `nlme` with `lme4` syntax for the weights: that doesn't work ...

Comment: glmer got a weights argument. What would be the correct sintax?

Answer (score 1):

I've already solved the issue. In glmer() the weights argument correspond to a vector of the same length that the original. To model the heteroscedaticity I generated a variance dataframe:

```
VAR<-aggregate(Lyc[,6],by=list(Lyc$Accesion), var)
colnames(VAR)<-c("Accesion", "Var")
```

That yields a dataframe Treatment/Variance, the head of it is:

```
 Accesion       Var
1       22  4.369281
2       23 16.251634
3       24 13.911765
4       25 15.404412
5       26 15.895833
6       27 44.838095
```

Then I create a new dataframe merging both dataframes

```
Lyc2<-merge(VAR, Lyc, by="Accesion")
```

And as I saw by doing it wrong 1 time, is needed to use the inverse variance, in order to correct the variance.

```
Lyc2$Var<-(1/Lyc2$Var)
```

After all the data steps, i run the code:

```
FTTglme = glmer(FTT ~ Accesion + Bloque + (1|Plot), data = Lyc2,    
family=poisson(link="log"), weights = Lyc2$Var)
```

That fixes the variance issue:

[image: Corrected variance residuals boxplot]

Comment: Good for you for solving the problem.  This isn't exactly the same as *estimating* the different variances for each group.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409340/how-to-allow-for-factor-specific-variance-of-random-effect-in-lme gives a link, but it's not terribly practical for your example since it requires setting up separate dummy variables for each group ...